# Python : trying to match and count words with regex (expected string or buffer)

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am trying to read a file and match words there has over 6 characters in it. but I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dummy.py", line 9, in <module>
    matches = re.findall("\w{6,}", f.read().split())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 181, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

And I can't figure out why I am getting this error? The code is pasted below

---

```
import re

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    matches = re.findall("\w{6,}", f.read().split())
    nr_long_words = len(matches)
    print (matches)
```

Comment: this is embarrising. it was just a typo........
used print (matches) instead of print(nr_long_words) and accedentialy added .split()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.read().split()` gives a list of strings, but `re.findall` expects a single string, thus the `TypeError: expected string or buffer`. You could apply the regex to each of the substrings in a loop or list comprehension, but you do not need to `split()` at all:

```
matches = re.findall("\w{6,}", f.read())
```

Note that if the file is very large, then `f.read()` might not be a good idea (but for text files it's probably not an issue, as those are rarely marger than a few megabytes, if at all). In this case, you could read the file line-by-line and sum up the long words per line:

```
nr_long_words = sum(len(re.findall(r"\w{6,}", line)) for line in f)
```

Also, as noted in comments, `\w{6,}` might not be the best regex for "long words" to start with. `\w` will, e.g., also match numbers or the underscore `_`. If you want to match exclusively (ascii-)letters, better use `[A-Za-z]`, but this might cause problems with non-ascii letters, such as umlauts, accents, arabic, etc. Also, you might want to include word boundary characters, i.e. `\b`, to make sure that the six letters are not part of a longer, non-word sequence, i.e. use a regex like `r'\b[A-Za-z]{6,}\b'`

Comment: Will `\b[A-Za-z]{6,}\b` be the correct regex to be used for matching **words** ?

Comment: @noob I thought about adding a bit on that topic: That `\w{6,}` could also match the "word"-part of a longer, non-word sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the great explanation so far! The only problem I've have left is that the regex doesn't detect words with æøå-ÆØÅ in it ? how could I add that ?

Comment: @DanielGuldbergAaes It seems like unicode support was added in Python 3, so `\w` will match those characters, but `[a-zA-Z]` does not. Alternatively, you could explicitly add them to the group: `[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅandthensomemore]`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re

nr_long_words = 0

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        matches = re.findall("\w{6,}", line)
        nr_long_words += len(matches)

    print(nr_long_words)
```

it should print count of words longer than 6 characters in file.